# Queuing theory applied to Akka

Tags: akka, queuing

I was wondering whether queuing theory can be sensibly applied to Akka in order to simulate actor systems for different workloads and processing times.

Does anyone have any experiences or ideas?

Thanks and best regards,
Michail

Answer (score 0):

It can, if you are able to take into account Akka and JVM intrinsics, such as:

when an actor executes, its thread can be interrupted by the clock or other hardware and yield to other thread

when you send a message, it is wrapped into an envelope object. To allocate memory for this object, the actor has to wait other allocations an/or garbage collector. In 99.99% this allocation is fast, but sometimes it can lag significantly.

when a message arrives to the destination actor, it waits for:

- previous messages to be processed
- free working thread in the thread pool
- free hardware processor